# Show specific "Info" ribbon in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins, ribbonx

I have a Word (2013/2016) AddIn that uploads a file to SharePoint.

After the upload i wanted that the user is redirected to the **"File->Info"** ribbon tab but I cannot find an example how this can be achieved. Well I do find some examples with `Globals.Ribbons..` but I cannot find my ribbon object in this collection.

I have a var: `ThisAddin.Application.ActiveDocument` and I thought the the ribbon must be somehow accessible through this, but there seems to be no method or property.

Any idea how I can redirect the user to this ribbon?

Comment: We don't have enough information. Are you using the Ribbon Designer or Ribbon XML in your VSTO project? Or have you not defined a Ribbon for the project?

Comment: @CindyMeister No, I don't use the Ribbon designer and I have not yet defined a ribbon for the project.

Comment: What, specifically, should the user work with in this tab? The only way I know to show the tab would be to use `SendKeys` which is notoriously unreliable. Best might be to bring the information of interest into a Windows Form or Custom Task Pane...

Comment: User should be presented the properties of the file, so he can edit the metadata which is then also synced to SharePoint (which happens out of the box).

Comment: So, that would be the Document Properties? There's a Pane in Word for that, which can be displayed between the Ribbon and the document: `ThisAddin.Application.DisplayDocumentInformationPanel = true;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's [workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCk0IFjXz7MSo-tD47) with all the required code and infrastructure to activate Home tab. In order to do it, you need:

1) Create Ribbon XML file.

2) Create callback which will be called upon loading ribbon.

3) Save ribbon object into variable.

4) Use `ActivateTabMso` method of ribbon.

**VBA**

```
Public ribbon As IRibbonUI

Sub OnRibbonLoaded(IRibbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set ribbon = IRibbon
End Sub

Sub ActivateHomeTab()
    ribbon.ActivateTabMso "TabHome"
End Sub
```

**Ribbon XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"
          onLoad="OnRibbonLoaded">
</customUI>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is necessary, to create the Ribbon XML file? Aren't the default tabs of the ribbon accessible some other way?

Comment: You need `IRibbonUI` object in order to activate tabs. The only way is as I showed.

Comment: I tested your code, but it fails because apparently the "TabInfo" I want to show is a BackStage tab and those cannot be opened using this method. I will search further.